# Selecting an element with textContent and then replacing an element ID

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of divs ('.program-collector') with dynamically generated IDs. Theses IDs are usually more than one word, so I used the strtok method in my PHP to reduce the IDs to the first word of the original multi-word ID string, which works fine.

**However**, two of the divs have the same first word ("Acting Basics" and "Acting Advanced"), so I am trying to identify the div with a heading within it that contains the *original* ID string of "Acting Basics" and replace it's ID with a new one ("Basics").

In my jquery, I attempted this method with the textContent property...

```
$('.program-collector').each(function(k,ttl) {
    if($(ttl).find("h3").textContent =="Acting Basics") {
        alert("Alert");
        $(ttl).attr("id","Basics");
    }
};
```

... but this doesn't trigger the alert popup or change the ID, so something in my code is off. Can anyone shed some light on how to improve my code or give advice on another method I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

`$(ttl).find("h3").textContent` should be `$(ttl).find("h3").text()`. `textContent` is a DOM property, not a jQuery method.

It's also possible that you have whitespace in the element. If it's not matching, try trimming it:

```
$('.program-collector').each(function(k,ttl) {
    if($(ttl).find("h3").text().trim() =="Acting Basics") {
        alert("Alert");
        $(ttl).attr("id","Basics");
    }
};
```

You could do this in a single call:

```
$('.program-collector:has(h3:contains("Acting Basics"))').attr('id', 'Basics');
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I'm still getting the same result, however.

Comment: Try trimming it before comparing, in case there's whitespace around the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version which does not require `each()` function.

```
$('.program-collector').find('h3:contains("Acting Basics")').closest('.program-collector').attr("id","Basics");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhx36p9f/

Comment: That adds the ID to the `h3`, not `.program-collector`.

Comment: That works, although your original attempt gave me the idea for the one-liner in my answer.

Comment: Thank you DinoMyte. Obviously your method works but I still can' t get anything to happen on my page, so there must be elements that are preventing the functionality for some reason.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with your html ? We can figure out why its not working